# Jquery AJAX request not coming out asynchronously?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to web design, and just started getting into jquery. I am trying to use a star rating system on my website where once a user clicks a star to rate it will refresh just the star rating system. Right now as it is I need to refresh the whole page before it refreshes and displays the average rating. This may be a dumb assumption but I assumed if you called a function which is itself an ajax request, that's all you would need to do for it to automatically refresh that area, depending on what you're doing of course. Below is the javascript code with the ajax request(s). This entire star rating system was one I got off a google search, there was a lot more to this file but I condensed the 'ReloadRating' function by a lot and still get the same result as what I was getting with how it was originally, so I left it like this. From taking a look at this, what else should I do for this to work like it was meant to with ajax? Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

```
function RateItem(varItemId, varRate)
{
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.rate.item.php",
type:"POST",
data:{item:varItemId,rating:varRate},
success:function(ReloadRating){
    alert(ReloadRating);
}
});
}
function ReloadRating(requestObj, jsonObj)
{
$.ajax({
url:"Rating::OutputRating",
type:"POST",
data:{$varItem:requestObj},
});
}
```

function Rating::OutputRating
    class Rating
      {

```
  // Output the Rating information
  // Returns a string of HTML
  public static function OutputRating($varItem)
  {
    // Verify $varItem was provided
   if ($varItem != null && strlen(trim($varItem)) != 0)
    {
      // Information for the Output
      $averageStars = Rating::CalculateAverageRating($varItem);

      // Check to see that the user has not already rated this item
      if (Rating::CheckRatingsByIp($varItem) == 0)
      {
        $classes      = Rating::ShowStars($averageStars);


        // Write Output HTML for the Rating Data
        $output  = "\r\n";
        $output .= "<ul class=\"rating . {$classes}\" id=\"{$varItem}\">\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"one\" ><a   href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 1);\" title=\"1 Star\">1</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"two\"><a   href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 2);\" title=\"2 Stars\">2</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"three\"><a href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 3);\" title=\"3 Stars\">3</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"four\"><a  href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 4);\" title=\"4 Stars\">4</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"five\"><a  href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 5);\" title=\"5 Stars\">5</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "</ul>\r\n";
      }
      else
      {
        $classes      = Rating::ShowStars($averageStars);

        // Write Output HTML for the Rating Data
        $output  = "\r\n";
        $output .= "<ul class=\"rating . {$classes}\" id=\"{$varItem}\">\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"one\">1</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"two\">2</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"three\">3</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"four\">4</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"five\">5</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "</ul>\r\n";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Simply making an ajax request isn't enough to refresh an area of the page. You have to actually do the "refresh" part yourself. The ajax request returns data, you have to ***do something*** with it. Your alert for example alerts the string value of the data. Don't you want to append it somewhere?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you would do to make the "refresh" part happen? Would you somehow look through to an earlier part of the code? Sorry for the rookie questions...I'm reallly new. Trying to get a grasp on some of this stuff.@KevinB

Comment: I don't know what you mean by append it somewhere

Comment: For exampmle, `$("#targetelement").append(ReloadRating)` or `$("#targetelement").html(ReloadRating)`

Comment: In that example, #targetelement would be the ID you want to refresh? With the ReloadRating function I have above, I want it to basically just re-run through the function Rating::OutputRating as if the page just loaded. Does that seem logical? @KevinB

Answer (score 1):

It is odd to have a `post` request to simply reload data.  That's more of a convention though.

As Keven B. mentions, you do have to do something with the request to update a page.  `$.ajax` in jQuery doesn't do anything by default.

http://api.jquery.com/load/ may be just the thing you're looking for.  It's a convenience helper on top of `$.ajax`.